# Python, Numpy array values added as ndarray instead of list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to write a simple portion of a program that pulls in a scoring matrix from a text file. I have the code working correctly with one file (PAM250.txt). However with my other file (Blosum62.txt) I am running into issues.

Specifically, after I import the data from the files, the data type of my scores_list is 'list'. Yet when I create the numpy array, in the PAM250 instance, the lists are added as type 'list' but in the Blosum62 instance, the lists are added as type 'numpy.ndarray'.

The data is stored a tad different between the two files, in the PAM250 the matrix is formatted with tabs whereas in the Blosum62 the data is formatted with spaces. Could this be causing a difference? When I print the intermediary lists they look the same to me. So I am wondering why in one instance the lists are added to the array as list and in the other instance as numpy.ndarray?

My code is below.

```
#Grab scoring matrix from text file
matrix_file = open(r'C:\Users\...\Blosum62.txt')
scores = matrix_file.readlines()
matrix_file.close()
scores_list = []
#delete tabs and white spaces between char in string and turn into lists
for index, row in enumerate(scores):
    row = row.split()
    scores_list.append(row)
score_matrix = np.asarray(scores_list)
```

Also I'm not sure if this is normal or strange, but in the working PAM250 array, the lists are all preceded by the word 'list', 
example output:

```
[list(['.', 'A', 'R', 'N', 'D'...])
 list(['A', '2', '-2',...],...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that somewhere in your Blosum62.txt file, there is some variability in how many spaces are in each row. So when you call `row = row.split()`, not all rows that are appended to your `scores_list` are the same. So then NumPy cannot make the conversion to a 2D array because of the size inconsistency. See the example below:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
arr = np.array([l1, l2])
print (arr)  # [list([1, 2, 3]) list([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])]
```

My recommendation would be to look through your Blosum62.txt file and determine exactly what you want scores_list to contain, then fix the file to make sure the formatting is correct.